# aws_lambda_permission, triggered by SES, will only work with a fixed source_arn

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-ses

I am having a problem in the following scenario. An AWS SES email address receives an email and triggers a lambda function. The lambda function starts, or stops, one instance, uses SQS and SNS as well as Cloudwatch logs. This is most of the code:

```
# aws_lambda_function.start-stop-one:
resource "aws_lambda_function" "start-stop-one" {
  architectures = [
    "x86_64",
  ]
  filename                       = "${path.module}/lambdas/start-instances.zip"
  function_name                  = "start-stop-one"
  handler                        = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  layers                         = []
  memory_size                    = 128
  package_type                   = "Zip"
  reserved_concurrent_executions = -1
  role                           = aws_iam_role.start-stop-one.arn
  runtime                        = "python3.9"
  skip_destroy                   = false
  source_code_hash               = data.archive_file.start-stop-one.output_base64sha256
  timeout                        = 180

  ephemeral_storage {
    size = 512
  }

  tracing_config {
    mode = "PassThrough"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "start-stop-one" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/lambdas/start-stop-one.py"
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambdas/start-stop-one.zip"
}

# aws_cloudwatch_log_group.start-stop-one:
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "start-stop-one" {
  name              = "/aws/lambda/start-stop-one"
  retention_in_days = 30
}

# aws_iam_policy.start-stop-one1:
resource "aws_iam_policy" "start-stop-one" {
  name      = "gwp-lambda-start-stop"
  path      = "/"
  policy    = jsonencode(
    {
      Statement = [
        {
          Action   = [
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeTags",
          ]
          Effect   = "Allow"
          Resource = "*"
        },
        {
          Effect   = "Allow"
          Action   = [
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
          ]
          Resource = [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:${data.aws_caller_identity.aws.account_id}:instance/*",
          ]
        },
        {
          Effect   = "Allow"
          Action   = [
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
          ]
          Resource = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.start-stop-one.arn}:*"
        },
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "sqs:SendMessage"
          ],
          "Resource": aws_sqs_queue.ingestion.arn
        },
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
          "Resource": aws_lambda_function.start-stop-one.arn,
          "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
              "AWS:SourceAccount": data.aws_caller_identity.aws.account_id
            },
            "ArnLike": {
              "AWS:SourceArn": aws_ses_receipt_rule.start-stop-one.arn
            }
          }
        }
      ]
      Version   = "2012-10-17"
    }
  )
}

# aws_iam_role.start-stop-one:
resource "aws_iam_role" "start-stop-one" {
  assume_role_policy    = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda-amazonaws-com.json
  force_detach_policies = false
  max_session_duration  = 3600
  name                  = "start-stop-one"
  path                  = "/"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "start-stop-one" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.start-stop-one.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.start-stop-one.arn
}


# aws_ses_receipt_rule.start-stop-one:
resource "aws_ses_receipt_rule" "start-stop-one" {
  enabled = true
  name    = "start-stop-one"
  recipients = [
    "startstopone@${var.client_id}.domain.com",
  ]
  rule_set_name = aws_ses_receipt_rule_set.identity_rset.rule_set_name
  scan_enabled  = true
  tls_policy    = "Optional"

  lambda_action {
    function_arn    = aws_lambda_function.start-stop-one.arn
    invocation_type = "Event"
    position        = 1
    topic_arn       = aws_sns_topic.start-stop-instances.arn
  }
}

# aws_lambda_permission.start-stop-one:
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "start-stop-one" {
  action         = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name  = aws_lambda_function.start-stop-one.function_name
  principal      = "ses.amazonaws.com"
  source_account = data.aws_caller_identity.aws.account_id
  #source_arn = "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:123456789:receipt-rule-set/start_stop_emr:receipt-rule/start-stop-one"
  source_arn = aws_ses_receipt_rule.start-stop-one.arn
}
```

If I run **terraform apply** i will get:

```
│ Error: creating SES Receipt Rule (start-stop-one): InvalidLambdaFunction: Could not invoke Lambda function: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:start-stop-one
│   status code: 400, request id: 4b3cad96-7bfa-4b18-8f69-34955d184f24
│ 
│   with aws_ses_receipt_rule.start-stop-one,
│   on lambda_start-stop-one.tf line 124, in resource "aws_ses_receipt_rule" "start-stop-one":
│  124: resource "aws_ses_receipt_rule" "start-stop-one" {
│
```

If I switch the **source_arn**, meaning comment the last one and uncomment the other, then it works perfectly. I have tried to use **depends_on** but to no avail or resulting in **cycle**. If I omit the **source_arn** then it works, but that’s not a good idea from a security perspective.

I did find a solution doing this:

```
# aws_lambda_permission.start-stop-one:
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "start-stop-one" {
  action         = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name  = aws_lambda_function.start-stop-one.function_name
  principal      = "ses.amazonaws.com"
  source_account = data.aws_caller_identity.aws.account_id
}

# aws_lambda_permission.start-stop-one:
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "start-stop-one-b" {
  action         = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name  = aws_lambda_function.start-stop-one.function_name
  principal      = "ses.amazonaws.com"
  source_account = data.aws_caller_identity.aws.account_id
  source_arn = aws_ses_receipt_rule.start-stop-one.arn
  depends_on = [
    aws_lambda_permission.start-stop-one
  ]
}
```

But it does not make sense to have to do this and besides when I run [tfsec](https://aquasecurity.github.io/tfsec/v1.28.1/) it returns a **Critical Error** for every occurrence of an **aws_lambda_permission** without a **source_arn**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did the same thing you did for the solution, by making a -b version of my lambda permission and it worked. Not sure why that is. Seems like a bug in Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

Using this *aws_ses_receipt_rule.start-stop-one.arn* as the source_arn could be an issue. Terraform needs to know the ARN of the receipt rule for the related SES. **If this Rule isnt created before the Lambda**  *(aws_lambda_permission.start-stop-one)* then the source_arn won't be available to Terraform and the creation of aws_lambda_permission will fail.

I can't test this but can you try the dependsOn?

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "start-stop-one" {
  action         = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name  = aws_lambda_function.start-stop-one.function_name
  principal      = "ses.amazonaws.com"
  source_account = data.aws_caller_identity.aws.account_id
  source_arn     = aws_ses_receipt_rule.start-stop-one.arn

  depends_on = [
    aws_ses_receipt_rule.start-stop-one
  ]
}
```

Comment: Terraform is already taking that into account due to the direct dependency, but it was the first thing I tried. The only solution I found was the one I posted above.